# Appending values into XSLT array

Tags: xml, xslt

How to add data into xslt array from outside the tag..

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="input-as-map" select="parse-json($input)" as="map(*)"/>
        <root>
            
            <!-- storing all the PERSONNUMBER present in the ibop -->
            <xsl:variable name="item-array" as="element()*">
                    <Item>A</Item>
                    <Item>A</Item>
                    <Item>A</Item>
                    <Item>b</Item>              
            </xsl:variable>   
        </root>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I'm adding the values inside an variable within the opening and closing `<xsl:variable>`  ..

So how to add values into an `item-array` based on `name` attribute(outside an variable tags)..

like how we do in other programs..*emphasized text*

Comment: You have a variable with a **sequence** of element nodes, not an *array* of element nodes. In XSLT 3, you can add to an array but it will also give you a new array. But your example binds a sequence of elements, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you can example of redeclaring and rebinding a variable you can use e.g.

```
   <xsl:variable name="elements" as="element(item)*">
        <item>a</item>
        <item>b</item>
        <item>c</item>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="elements" as="element(item)*">
        <xsl:sequence select="$elements"/>
        <item>d</item>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$elements"/>
```

and you will get

```
  <item>a</item>
  <item>b</item>
  <item>c</item>
  <item>d</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So how to add values into an item-array based on name attribute(outside an variable tags)..

You can't. All XSLT variables are immutable.

If you want to have a variable with a different value, create a new one.